# How to join Enum with JavaScript in Spring-Boot application

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring-boot

I'm a beginer with JavaScript and now I'm facing such problem.
I have an enum

```
@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.OBJECT)
public enum FinancialEventType {

  Income("Income"),
  Expense("Expense");
  
  private String code;
  
  private FinancialEventType(String code) {
    this.code = code;
  }
  
  @JsonValue
  public String getCode() {
    return this.code;
  }
}
```

and I'd like to pass the enum to my view trough a ModelAttribute(as an object and as an JSON)

```
  @ModelAttribute()
  public void addAttributes(Model model) throws JsonProcessingException {
    String data1 = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(FinancialEventType.values());
    
    model.addAttribute("data1", data1);
    model.addAttribute("eventTypes",     FinancialEventType.values());
  }
```

in my view I can get these attributes

```
  <script>
    var documentDate = "[[${documentDate}]]";
    var eventTypes = "[[${eventTypes}]]";
    var data1 = "[[${data1}]]";
    console.log("data1: " + data1);
  </script>
```

but the "JSON" looks a bit weird:

```
data1: [&quot;Income&quot;,&quot;Expense&quot;]
```

and when I try the generate a dropdown element via the JavaScript

```
//Create and append the options
    for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = data1[i];
        option.text = data1[i];
        selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
    row.appendChild(cell);
```

the generated list is not what I'm looking for:
[image]

thanks for any advice
Witold

Comment: The correct result should be `[ 'Income', 'Expense' ]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
var data1 = "[[${data1}]]";
```

for this:

```
var data1 = [(${data1})];
```

Using "[[ ]]" in Thymeleaf is equivalent to use th:text, and Thymeleaf is escaping the text (that means, converting the symbol ' in the HTML equivalent &quot). So, use "[( )]" instead, which is equivalent to th:utext.

This will only work with Thymeleaf version 3, not version 2.

Source: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining

Comment: Thanks,but with this syntax the script is trying to evaluate this expression  
  
    `var data1 = "["Income","Expense"]";`

which leads to:
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

instead of   
    `var data1 = "['Income','Expense']";`

Comment: Remove the double quote here: "[(${data1})]", and leave it like this [(${data1})]. This will leave var data1 = ["Income","Expense"], which is totally valid in JS. I edited my answer to correct this. In JS ["Income","Expense"] is as valid as ['Income','Expense']

Comment: By the way, the error you are receiving in the HTML select is because your are enclosing the array with the quotes. The expression "['Income','Expense']" is wrong because data1 will be a String. Without the double quote, it will be an array. That's why data1.length is something like 20 and you have so many options, when it should be only 2.